# Executing external program from shortcut

Tags: java, shortcut, execute

I'm trying to open a program from my desktop within java. Some of my desktop icon properties have a *.exe extension, but other program shortcuts have a *.lnk extension. As this will open a program with `param` being the location of an *.exe:

```
try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
        int result = p.waitFor();

        if (result != 0) {
            System.out.println("Process failed with status: " + result);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this doesn't work for any other shortcut with a different extension.

Is there a way I can target the proper application the shortcut is pointing to and open it?

Comment: `.lnk` is not an executable format.  I'm not sure exactly what magic goes into opening them, but you should be able to get it to work if you launch "cmd -c path\to\MyShortcut.lnk" and let the command prompt figure out how it's supposed to launch.  You might also experiment with something like "explorer.exe path\to\shortcut.lnk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java.awt.Desktop ;    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("*.lnk"));